# Uso de variables Bind en Oracle cuando no hay variables

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

¿Tiene alguna utilidad usar variables bind cuando no hay variables?

Por ejemplo

```
SELECT count(1) as cantidad
FROM MYTABLA
WHERE CAMPO1=5
```

Este query siempre se ejecutara igual, el 5 siempre sera 5 y no variara.

Hasta donde se Oracle guarda el plan de ejecución de esta setentencia y para la proxima vez que se solicite una ejecución a Oracle, Oracle en lugar de analizar el Query buscara en su area de SGA y procedera.

¿Tiene alguna ventaja usar una variable Bind que nunca cambiara su valor?

Esto lo pregunto por que un experto de oracle dijo:

```
"Al usar constantes en cada ejecución, causa que se genere un sql id diferente debido al hard parse en la base de datos, haciendo imposible adjuntar un profile a la query."
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que dices es correcto.  Si el valor no es variable, no hay ventaja en emplear un parameter bind.

Lo que el experto quiso decir es que si ejecutaras el query varias veces con constantes pero de *valores distintas*, entonces esto causaría problemas. Por ejemplo, si ejecutaras los siguientes queries:

```
SELECT count(1) as cantidad
FROM MYTABLA
WHERE CAMPO1=5

SELECT count(1) as cantidad
FROM MYTABLA
WHERE CAMPO1=50

SELECT count(1) as cantidad
FROM MYTABLA
WHERE CAMPO1=500
```

Debido a que usas 3 constantes *distintas*, Oracle considera que cada sentencia es distinta, y esto lo obliga a hacer un *hard parse* para cada una, lo que tiene un efecto negativo en la concurrencia y la memoria.

En ese caso, sería mejor emplear un *bind variable* de esta manera:

```
SELECT count(1) as cantidad
FROM MYTABLA
WHERE CAMPO1=:campoParam
```

Pero esto no aplica a tu caso. Como el valor nunca cambia, Oracle solo haría el *hard parse* la primera vez que ejecutas el query y no mas.